# JSF 2.2 multipart form is not getting submitted

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jboss7.x, jsf-2.2

When I upload a file in jsf 2.2 project with jboss 7.1
its prevent to submit form.
help me out....

here is sample code for upload a file

This is my welcome.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form  enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
    <h:outputLabel value="Upload File : " />
    <h:inputFile value="#{myController.file}"/> 
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{myController.mycontroller}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Here is my backing bean MyController.java

```
public class MyController {

    private Part file;
    public Part getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(Part file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public String mycontroller() throws IOException {

        System.out.println("--call mycontroller method--");

        UploadFile uf = new UploadFile();

        boolean b = uf.upload(getFile());
        System.out.println(b);

        return "success.xhtml";
    }
  }
```

**Edit:1**
I have one form with file upload and a `<h:commandButton>`, where I want to get uploaded file's information. Problem I am facing, the button is not firing when I added `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. So any advice will be helpful to me.

Comment: your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I copy pasted your code and it worked as expected. The only addition I made is to add `@ViewScoped` and `@ManagedBean` annotation to `MyController`.

Comment: Thank You for your response.This issue happened for JSF version mismatch and I solved this issue.